# Google App Scripts Remove ALL Files in Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

Good morning, I am running into some issues when creating a google app scripts to remove all files/folders from the root of the Google Drive. I have found the following code but it appears to error out when running;

```
function deleteFile(idToDLET) {
  idToDLET = 'the File ID';

  //This deletes a file without needing to move it to the trash
  var rtrnFromDLET = Drive.Files.remove(idToDLET);
}
```

Error Code = Script function not found; myFunction

Thanks

Comment: You haven't saved the script. myFunction is the default function when you open a new script file. If you've had to ask this question I have a feeling it will be the least of your problems!

Comment: I am not a programmer, I am simply trying to make the HR departments life easier, as a help desk technician, thanks for that ;)

Comment: This is like `sudo rm -rf */*`...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @CTOverton answer, I've created another version as I noticed that a File has the setTrashed method, which moves the file in the trash bin.

If the Drive has important files saved, I'd suggest to move files to trash instead of doing a permanent deletion, it may save you from a disaster while doing scripting experiments :-)

This version uses a folder id which you can get with: `folder.getId()`.

You can use CTOverton's code to delete all files on your Drive (commented).

```js
function emptyFolder(folderId) {

    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
    while (folder.getFiles().hasNext()) {
      const file = folder.getFiles().next();
      Logger.log('Moving file to trash: ', file);
      file.setTrashed(true);
      // Delete File
      //Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())
  }

}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As @James D said, you are missing the myFunction which is the default function in order to run the script. Make sure to save your script first.

Here is the code to get all the files and delete them.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get all files in Drive
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();

  // Delete every file
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log('Deleting file "%s"',
                 file.getName());
    // Delete File
    Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())
  }
}
```

In order to use DriveAPI, you need to add it through the **Resources>Advanced Google Services** menu. Set the Drive API to **ON**. ***AND*** make sure that the Drive API is turned on in your Google Developers Console. If it's not turned on in **BOTH** places, it won't be available.

[image: Enable Drive API]

### WARNING

Apps scripts are stored as files in Google Drive...

This script upon running will remove any and all files in the connected google drive account, including itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, the script now errors on line 18 "Drive is not defined" I have verified the Drive API is activated, am I missing anything else? Thanks

Comment: @APineapple You have to enable the Drive API. I edited the answer to explain how to do this and made the code simpler.

Comment: You should probably be using [`Drive.Files.delete()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete).

Comment: I tried this and it says `Insufficient permissions for this file (line 11, file "Code")`

Comment: @James I believe that is because it is trying to delete itself. Apps Scripts are stored in google drive too. Try adding an if statement that check to make sure it isn't the code itself. Ex: `if !(file.getName() == "Code") {Drive.Files.remove(file.getId())}`